# Portable https solution for node.js using express framework

Tags: node.js, express, https, ssl-certificate

I've made a node.js application which hosts a webserver over http using the express framework but i'd like to upgrade to https.

However I can't seem to find a good way to do this since the application will be run on different PCs which could have different public IP addresses so pre-generating a certificate wouldn't be possible.

Furthermore if possible I'd like to keep the application as portable as possible so locally installing open-ssl or expecting it is locally installed isn't really an option unless it can be packaged with the server itself somehow.

How would one go about building what I've described above?
If anyone could give me some pointers that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker/kubernetes together with a reverse proxy that automatically generates SSL certificates. I can recommend Traefik.

Comment: As mentioned in the question i'd like the solution to be as portable as possible. I can't expect all the people who want to run the server application to have docker installed so this solution sadly won't work for me or I might be misunderstanding what you intended with your anwser, if so please elaborate.

Comment: Then you'd have to write an installer that generates certificates. There is no other way of doing it as far as I know.